# How do I disable the command mention in echo?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

[image: sample command with mention]

I want to clear the mention of my action but I don't know how. Here is the code for my `/echo` command:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const data = new SlashCommandBuilder();

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('echo')
    .setDescription('Replies with your input!')
    .addStringOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName('input')
        .setDescription('The input to echo back')
        .setRequired(true)
    ),
  async execute(interaction) {
    const input = interaction.options.getString('input');
    await interaction.reply({ content: 'Message sent!', ephemeral: true });
    await interaction.followUp(input);
  },
};
```

I have tried `interaction.reply`, but it doesn't work for using the same function multiple times.

Comment: Not sure if I can understand your question but you probably want to use `interaction.channel.send(input)` instead of `interaction.followUp(input)`?

Answer (score 0):

Doing [`interaction.reply()`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/ChatInputCommandInteraction?scrollTo=reply) will always generate a "command mention", as you have shown. If you don't want that to happen, use [`<channel>.send()`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) instead. But be aware that `<channel>.send()` does not support ephemeral messages.